# Can't use FluidTransitions with React-Native-Navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-navigation, shared-element-transition

I am using [React-Native-Navigation](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation) which do not have this method:

```
props.navigation.navigate('screen2')}
```

Also, React-Native-Navigation does not allow us to create a stackNavigator. It directly registers the screens.
So, how can I use [FluidTransition](https://github.com/fram-x/FluidTransitions) library?

Any help would be appreciated

> Although, the React-Native-Navigation has SharedElementTransition
>   integrated but it is not as smooth as FluidTransition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FluidTransition library is only supported for the [React Navigation library](https://reactnavigation.org/). However, the React-Native-Navigation have implemented their own version of shared element transition which can be found in their [docs](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/docs/animations?id=shared-element).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I have implemented the transition using react-native-navigation, but it only works for iOS.